# Redux ngrx 6 states lost after refresh or routing to new module

Tags: angular, reactjs, ngrx-store

I am new to ngrx6 and angular 6
I using ngrx6 and have created 2 states model: 'user'  and 'bills' .
user state have his outstanding dues and login status details.
and Bill state have bills and there status.

Then I create the app state

```
export interface ApplicationState {
    user: fromUserReducer.UserState;
    bill: fromBillReducer.BillState;
}


export const appReducers: ActionReducerMap<ApplicationState> = {
    user: fromUserReducer.reducers,
    bill: fromBillReducer.BillState;
};
```

Then I have passed this appReducer to my main app module (I have more module inside  it.)
this is the current module structure.
Main module > User Module > Bill Module > multiple compnents

Now the issue is :
when I go to home page I can see User state successfully filled with user data, but the moment i go to bill page, User state data is lost and set to default state but bill state is filled with correct data.

I am new to ngrx so not sure if I still need to develop something to hold on to the states while going one module to other.
any help will help .
Links are appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a default switch case inside your reducers that returns the state?

Comment: Yes, I do have it.

Comment: appReducers initialization is not correct in your question. You set BillState in place of reducer for bill. Maybe just an error in the question?